# Understanding bytes from wav audio data

Tags: java, audio, wav

I am novel handling audio. I am trying to understand how the audio wav file works. I get the bytes with a java code and then render the first 1500 samples in an excel file. This is the image from Audacity:
[AudacityImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ySb1.png)
And this is the representation in Excel:
[ExcelImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzNNb.png)

I can see the wave but I don't know what the peaks mixed with the original signal are. Can someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may yet need to do another important step in order for the Excel image to be meaningful. If the wav data is 16-bit or 24-bit or 32-bit encoding, the bytes need to be appended into PCM data. 8-bit values (+/- 128) are not used so often any more for encoding waveforms. Shorts (16-bit, +/- 32767) give much better fidelity. Check the format to see the encoding and the byte order (may be either big-endian or little-endian) and number of tracks (mono or stereo) and assemble your PCM values accordingly and I bet you will get the desired result.

The tutorial provided by Oracle, [Overview of the Sampled Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html), goes over basic concepts and tools that will be helpful in the Java context.